# Comparing Columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with racing results.

```
   Place BibNum Time 
0   1     2      5:50 
1   2     4      8:09 
2   3     7      10:27 
3   4     3      11:12 
4   5     1      12:13 
... 
34  1     5      2:03 
35  2     9      4:35 
36  3     7      5:36
```

What I would like to know is how can I get a count of how many times the BibNum showed up where the Place was 1, 2, 3 etc?

I know that I can do a "value_counts" but that is for how many times it shows up in a single column. I also looked into using numpy "where" but that is using a conditional like greater than or less than.

Comment: If you want a matrix: `pd.crosstab(df['Place'], df['BibNum'])`, else `df[['Place', 'BibNum']].value_counts()`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC  , this is what you need:

```
out = df.groupby(['Place','BibNum']).size()
```